# send file through socket c# and java application

Tags: java, sockets

hi guys i am trieng to send files  through socket c# and java application using eclipse.when i put the file to send under eclipse project it worked but when i put under c:// or D:// it didn't work here is the code i used 
server

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Server {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub}
        sendFile("‪‪c:\\cassandraTest.csv");
    }
    public static Boolean sendFile(String strFileToSend) {
        try {
            ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(1592);
            Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
            System.out.println("Connection accepted from " + socket);
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
            File file = new File(strFileToSend);
            // send file length
            out.println(file.length());
            // read file to buffer
            byte[] buffer = new byte[(int) file.length()];
            DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
            dis.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
            // send file
            BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(
                    socket.getOutputStream());
            bos.write(buffer);
            bos.flush();
            // added
            dis.close();
            serverSocket.close();
            return true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
    }



}
```

for the client

```
 public static bool receiveFile(string ip,string strFilePath)
        {   
            try
            {
                TcpClient tcpClient = new TcpClient();
                tcpClient.Connect(ip, 1592);
                NetworkStream networkStream = tcpClient.GetStream();
                StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(networkStream);
                //read file length
                int length = int.Parse(sr.ReadLine());
                //read bytes to buffer
                byte[] buffer = new byte[length];
                networkStream.Read(buffer, 0, (int)length);
                //write to file
                BinaryWriter bWrite = new BinaryWriter(File.Open(strFilePath, FileMode.Create));
                bWrite.Write(buffer);
                bWrite.Flush();
                bWrite.Close();
                return true;
            }
            catch(Exception exException)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(exException.Message);
                return false;
            }

        }
```

It worked only if the file is under eclipse, otherwise i got the following exception from the server application
[image]

Comment: It cannot find the file, make sure the application or you yourself have sufficient privileges to the C:\ root directory.

Comment: @Chad i have tried both C;/ and D:/ the same problem.would you please try under your machine jutst to verify .Thanks

Comment: I don't have Eclipse IDE readily available to test but, one thing you can check is the extension case of your file. Please make sure that the actual file has a lower case .csv extension, and not .CSV.  Case matters in this case.

Comment: @Chad , just checked CSV it is all in lower case.

Comment: The filename literal may have a funny character in it. Retype it all and retry.